# Creating new account fails with INSUFFICIENT_TX_FEE

Tags: python, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I've been playing around with the Hedera SDK and with it's wrapper for Python. A couple of hours ago I had a working example were I was able to create a new account with an initial balance.

Now, a couple of hours later, the same code is failling with the following error (**Testnet**):

```
Exception has occurred: JavaException
JVM exception occurred: Hedera transaction `0.0.29467648@1642981813.928678616` failed pre-check with the status `INSUFFICIENT_TX_FEE` com.hedera.hashgraph.sdk.PrecheckStatusException
  File "/home/.../src/utils/hedera.py", line 101, in __init__
    AccountCreateTransaction()
  File "/home/.../src/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    new_account: HederaAccount = HederaAccount(client, initial_balance=100_000)
```

I've been trying to find the root cause and fix but no luck so far (oficial docs/github/anywhere). I found some comments in GitHub where it was mentioned that you must specify the max transaction fee when configuring the client with a value greater than 100_000 tinybars. I did it but still the same error.

This is the helper function I'm using to configure the client:

```py
def get_client(
    account_id: Optional[AccountId] = None, private_key: Optional[PrivateKey] = None
) -> Client:
    logger.debug(f"Hedera::get_client - create account_id")
    _account_id: AccountId = (
        account_id if account_id else Hedera.load_account_from_id()
    )

    logger.debug(f"Hedera::get_client - create account_id")
    private_key: PrivateKey = (
        private_key
        if private_key
        else Hedera.load_private_key(config["account"]["private_key"])
    )

    logger.debug(f"Hedera::get_client - create client")
    client: Client = (
        Client.forTestnet()
        if config["env"] == DeploymentEnv.Development.value
        else Client.forMainnet()
    )

    logger.debug(f"Hedera::get_client - set operator")
    client.setOperator(_account_id, private_key)

    # I just added this line (not required a couple of hours ago), still same error
    client.setMaxTransactionFee(Hbar.fromTinybars(200_000))

    logger.debug(f"Hedera::get_client - client: {client.toString()}")
    return client
```

And this is the class where the new account is created and where the error is thrown:

```py
class HederaAccount:
    def __init__(
        self,
        client,
        account_id: Optional[AccountId] = None,
        private_key: Optional[PrivateKey] = None,
        initial_balance: Optional[int] = 1_000_000,
    ) -> None:
        self.client: Client = client

        if account_id:
            logger.debug(
                f"HederaAccount::init - existent account id: {account_id.toString()}"
            )

            if not private_key:
                raise Exception(
                    "When loading an existing account, 'private_key' is required"
                )

            self.account_id = account_id
            self.private_key = private_key
            self.public_key = self.private_key.getPublicKey()
            self.node_id: Optional[AccountId] = None

        else:
            self.private_key: PrivateKey = PrivateKey.generate()
            self.public_key: PublicKey = self.private_key.getPublicKey()

            tx_resp: TransactionResponse = (
                AccountCreateTransaction()
                .setKey(self.public_key)
                .setInitialBalance(Hbar.fromTinybars(initial_balance))
                .execute(client)
            )
            self.node_id: AccountId = tx_resp.nodeId

            tx_receipt: TransactionReceipt = tx_resp.getReceipt(self.client)
            self.account_id: AccountId = tx_receipt.accountId

            logger.debug(
                f"HederaAccount::init - new account id: {self.account_id.toString()}"
            )
```

And this is how I'm creating/loading my accounts:

```
root_account_id = Hedera.load_account_id()
root_private_key = Hedera.load_private_key()
client = Hedera.get_client(account_id=root_account_id, private_key=root_private_key)

# Load root account (no problems here)
root_account: HederaAccount = HederaAccount(
    client, account_id=root_account_id, private_key=root_private_key
)
logger.info(f"Root account: {root_account}")
logger.info("\n\n")

# Create a new account (Failing here)
new_account: HederaAccount = HederaAccount(client, initial_balance=100_000)
logger.info(f"New account: {new_account}")
logger.info("\n\n")
```

Since I'm running my code in the Testnet, my account (root_account) has enough HBARs to pay the fees to create the new account (new_account).

**hedera-sdk-py**: 2.6.0

**Repo:** https://github.com/ccddan/hbar-hello-world/blob/feature/nfts/src/nft.py

Any hint is welcome, including links to **good** Hedera documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, at the time of this writing, the minimum amount for `client.setMaxTransactionFee()` **must be 1 HBAR**. This is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation and you cannot try with lower values:

https://docs.hedera.com/guides/getting-started/environment-set-up

[docs screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lAKL.png)

After updating my client configuration with `client.setMaxTransactionFee(Hbar(1))` everything works as expected

Comment: It's a bit frustrating that this is not mentioned in the Hedera docs in terms of environment setup.  It seems like a simple thing and I'm not sure why you can't explicitly set per transaction rather than when setting the client